# Invalidate session of other user

Tags: asp.net, cas

I've made an asp.net site, which uses Session objects to store information for each logged in user. To check if a user is still logged in, I check if a certain object exists in the Session.

The system used Jasig CAS authentication, and the single sign on part works (as in: after the log in, the Session object of the user is set up correctly).

CAS also supports single sign out. The way this happens is that CAS calls a url on my site, with some parameters about the CAS session.

What I need to do now, is invalidate all Session objects for the specified user.

How can I, from a page on my site, invalid the Session object of a random other user? Is there a db I can clear, is it all in memory (I can look at web.config if I know what to look for)?

I've seen this question asked before, and most answers are "keep a global variable next to the Session global variable, and check that one too to see if the user should be logged out or not", but I don't like that solution...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The session is by design private to individual users. Therefore to abandon it, it has to be done by the user.

So you might have to use another a list & check that.

Ideally though, you shouldn't tie your authentication state to the session. Whether the user is authenticated or not should be independent. You can then choose to abandon the session by querying the authentication state. It also makes it easier to implement mechanisms like counting logged in users & ensuring login from only 1 location - should you require these.